# Array debugging C?

Tags: c, arrays

An assignment in the K&R C Programming 2nd edition says that I have to write a program to print a histogram of the lengths of words in its input. I believe I know how to do so, but when running a test program on arrays, which I have only just learned about, all I get is "8", no matter what I input. This is the program so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* write a program to print a histogram
of the lengths of words in its input */
main()
{
      int wl[11];
      int cc, c;

      while ((c=getchar()) != EOF);
      {
            if (c != ' ')
               ++cc;
            if (c == ' ' && cc == '1')
            {
               ++wl[0];
               c = 0;
            }
       putchar(wl[0]);
      }
}
```

It may be just because I'm a total beginner in programming, but I honestly cannot see where I went wrong here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In addition to the other answers, remove the semicolon at the end of the while statement; otherwise, the while will read all the input before moving on to the next line.

Comment: Thanks to everyone's help, I have now successfully got the program working. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

Start by initializing your variables:

```
int wl[11] = {0};
int cc = 0;
```

By default, memory contains garbage in C.

EDIT: *Beyond the Obvious*

- the comparison `cc == '1'` does not do what you expect.  It should probably be `cc == 1`
- my guess is that `++wl[0]` should be `++wl[cc]`.  This assumes a maximum word length of 11.
- `c = 0` should be resetting `cc` instead - `c` is the current character, `cc` is the current word length
- `putchar` needs a character not an `int` so you will need to solve that as well

Good start though.

Comment: Yup.  `printf` is what you want here.  You probably want the `printf` outside of the `while` as well.

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of problems here.

```
main()
```

Though it was fairly common to omit the return type at that time, it isn't any more. You probably want to write this as:

```
int main()
```

Instead.

```
{
      int wl[11];
```

As @D.Shawley already pointed out, this will contain garbage.

```
      int cc, c;
```

What he forgot to point out was that these will too. This doesn't matter much for `c`, but does for `cc`.

```
      while ((c=getchar()) != EOF);
      {
            if (c != ' ')
               ++cc;
```

Here you're incrementing `cc`, but you never set it to a known value first, so you have no idea what it started as, or (therefore) what result your increment will produce.

```
            if (c == ' ' && cc == '1')
```

I'm guessing you don't really want `'1'` here -- you probably just want `1`. That is, you don't want to compare `cc` to the digit `'1'`, but to the value 1.

```
            {
               ++wl[0];
               c = 0;
```

Though it's harmless, zeroing `c` doesn't accomplish much here -- maybe you wanted to zero `cc`? I'm not sure what you're really trying to do though. At a guess, you probably don't want to increment `wl[0]` either.

```
            }
       putchar(wl[0]);
```

You probably don't want `putchar` here either -- you probably want to write out `wl[0]` as an int or (to produce a histogram) use it as the count of something like '*' to print out.

Comment: @KeithThompson: What's the benefit for a function you never call anyway? Or are you honestly recommending a recursive main (outside of the IOCCC anyway)?

Comment: Why wouldn't I want to increment wl[0]? If I didn't, I wouldn't be able to get the program to do what I want. Perhaps I'm not seeing something you are.

Comment: @user1509423: Presumably you want to count up the number of letters in a word, then increment the int in the array that corresponds to that length. When you print them out, you probably want to print out more than wl[0] as well.

Comment: @Keith int main(int argc, char *argv[]); is probably more correct for a system with STDIN and STDOUT ;-)

Comment: @JerryCoffin: The C standard mentions `int main(void)` and `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`, or equivalent forms. Any other forms are permitted as implementation-defined extensions, but are not guaranteed to be accepted. `int main()` is not *quite* equivalent to `int main(void)`. And `int main()` is an old-style function definition; IMHO it's best to avoid those.

Comment: @JoshPetitt: `argc` and `argv` are not related to `stdin` and `stdout`. The C standard explicitly permits both `int main(void)` and `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`.

Comment: @Keith, ah ok thank you.  I've only seen int main(void) used on systems without stdio support (e.g. embedded systems)

Comment: @JoshPetitt: I should mention that those two forms are mandated for hosted implementations; for freestanding implementations (more or less embedded systems), the program entry point is entirely implementation-defined.

Comment: @KeithThompson: The C99 standard includes examples using `int main()`, but I guess the guys who wrote that didn't know C as well as you do.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: You're right; I hadn't noticed that before. And they're still in the 2011 standard. As I'm sure you know, though, examples are not normative. My reading of 5.1.2.2.1 is that compilers needn't support `int main()`, though I suspect the authors' *intent* was to allow it for backward compatibility. (I argue that `int main()` is not "equivalent" to `int main(void)`, because the latter requires a diagnostic for a call like `main(42)`, whereas the former does not.) Note that `int main()` is an old-style definition, which is deprecated (see 6.77.1). BTW, feel free to drop the sarcasm.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use argc and argv here (look this up in your C book).  The nice thing about this is it gives you the number of words and you don't have to handle input yourself (let the OS and your standard library handle it).  You could malloc the sizes array (the histogram buckets), but you could also make a "reasonable" assumption that will get the majority of English words (hopefully you aren't German :-) ).

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// assume longest word is "Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious"    
#define MAX_WORD_LENGTH    (35)

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  size_t sizes[MAX_WORD_LENGTH] = {0};

  for (int i=0; i<argc; ++i)
  {
    size_t len = strlen(argv[i]);

    if (len < MAX_WORD_LENGTH)
    {
      ++sizes[len]; // increment bucket
    }
    else
    {
      ++sizes[0]; // too long, put in default bucket
    }
  }

  // print the buckets
  for (int i=1; i<MAX_WORD_LENGTH; ++i)
  {
    printf("%d ", sizes[i]); 
  }

  // print the default bucket
  printf("%d", sizes[0]);
}
```